c++ Mongo Interface
This questions needs some set up.
I have some code that serializes C++ objects into JSON/YAML/BSON.
Code here review here.
Simply you can serialize and de-serialize C++ objects to a std::iostream.
std::cout << ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonExporter(object); // prints JSON
std::cin  >> ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonImporter(object); // reads  JSON

In addition to that I have an implementation of std::iostream that uses a UNIX (or Windows) socket as the underlying stream. So you can now send objects across a socket. Code here with early review here.
I came across Mongo DB (at work). They have a very unique interface for their wire API that is all about documents. And I can stream documents into a wire format (BSON) with my existing library. So lets see if we can make a simple C++ wrapper that makes using Mongo trivial with C++.
So I am thinking the code should look like this:
class Address
{
    std::string  street;
    std::string  state;
    int          zip;
};
class Person
{
    std::string  name;
    int          age;
    Address      address;
};
struct AgeLessThan
{
    ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::LE              age;
};
struct AgeGreaterThan
{
    ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::GT              age;
};
struct FindByName
{
    std::string     name;
};
// For reference the LE class looks like this:
// Side affect of the Mongo library being document based
// is that all commands becomes a structure that is then
// simply serialized onto the wire as BSON.
// struct LE
// {
//        int             $lte;
// };

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> people{{"Martin", 50, {"Seattle", "WA", 98121}},..etc..}};

    using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::DB;
    using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Collection;
    using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::Query;
    using ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::ReadConfigBuilder;

    DB  db(<host>, <port>, <username>, <password>, <databaseName>);
    Collection  collection(db, "People");

    // Add "People" objects to the "collection"
    collection.insert(people);

    // Delete a "People" record
    collection.del(std::tie(Query<AgeLessThan>{48}, Query<FindByName>{"Bob"}));

    // Find people in the DB
    collection.find<Person>(Query<AgeGreaterThan>{18}, ReadConfigBuilder{}.batchSize(5).build());
}

So the above is the goal (I have a working implementation).
Also interested in opinions on the interface.
Most of the functionality is specified in the Collection class.
You will see a lot of classes that are not included here (like HandShake, HandShakeReply, AuthInit, AuthCont, AuthReply, Inserter, Deleter, Finder). That is deliberate. These classes do not contain any code and are simply objects that hold data. They mirror the definition of the mongo commands in their layout. The serialization library does all the work and automatically converts the C++ object into a BSON object on the stream that mirrors these types. There is nothing in the actually object apart from the data being transferred.
Part 1:
All messages to Mongo are an Op_Msg.
So we have a wrapper object that can send data to and receive data from Mongo. The class Op_MsgObj wrappes a reference to Section that is the actual payload we want to send to Mongo (which is usually a mongo command and some data).
  /*
   * Send integer to/from stream in little endian form
   * Handles   16/32/64 bit values.
   *
   * Used like:
   *
   *      std::int32_t    value = 5;
   *
   *      // Write a little endian version of value to the file stream.
   *      file << make_LE(value);
   *      // Outputs  05 00 00 00
   *
   *      // Read a little endian version of value from the file stream.
   *      file >> make_LE(value);
   *      // Input   05 00 00 00  will be read into value and be int{5}
   */
  template<typename Type>
  struct LittleEndian
  {
      using T  = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Type>>;
      using UT = std::make_signed_t<T>;
      using ST = std::make_signed_t<UT>;
      T&   value;
      LittleEndian(Type&& value)
          : value(value)
      {}
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, LittleEndian<Type> const& data)
      {
          ST   output = boost::endian::native_to_little(static_cast<ST>(static_cast<UT>(data.value)));
          stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&output), sizeof(output));
          return stream;
      };
      friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, LittleEndian<Type> const& data)
      {
          ST   input;
          stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&input), sizeof(input));
          data.value = static_cast<T>(boost::endian::little_to_native(input));
          return stream;
      }
  };

  template<typename T>
  LittleEndian<T> make_LE(T&& value)               {return LittleEndian<T>(std::forward<T>(value));}


  template<typename Section>
  class Op_MsgObj
  {
      private:
          static std::int32_t getNextMessageId()
          {
              static std::int32_t  nextMessageId = 0;
              return nextMessageId++;
          }

          Section&            section;
      protected:
              mutable ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ParserConfig    config;
              // Used for reading only
              // Message Header
              mutable std::int32_t    messageLength;
              mutable std::int32_t    requestId;
              mutable std::int32_t    responseTo;
              mutable std::int32_t    opCode;
              // Message Body
              mutable OP_MsgFlag      flags;
              mutable char            kind;
              mutable std::int32_t    checksum;

      public:
          Op_MsgObj(Section&& section)
              : section(section)
          {}
          bool            hasCheckSum() const {return false;}
          std::int32_t    getFlags()    const {return 0;}

          friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Op_MsgObj const& message)
          {
              std::int32_t    messageLength =  0
                          // Size of Header
                          + sizeof(std::int32_t)      // MessageSize
                          + sizeof(std::int32_t)      // requestId
                          + sizeof(std::int32_t)      // responseTo
                          + sizeof(std::int32_t)      // OpCode
                          // Op_Msg Body
                          + sizeof(std::int32_t)      // Flags
                          // Op_Msg_Section
                          + sizeof(char)              // Kind Marker
                          + ThorsAnvil::Serialize::bsonGetPrintSize(message.section)
                          // Op_Msg Body
                          + (message.hasCheckSum() ? sizeof(std::int32_t) : 0);

              stream  // Message Header
                      << make_LE(messageLength)
                      << make_LE(getNextMessageId())
                      << make_LE(0)
                      << make_LE(OpCode{OpCode::OP_MSG})
                      // Message Body
                      << make_LE(message.getFlags())
                      // Section Kind 0
                      << static_cast<char>(0)
                      << ThorsAnvil::Serialize::bsonExporter(message.section);
              if (message.hasCheckSum())
              {
                  std::int32_t    checksum = 0;
                  stream << make_LE(checksum);
              }
              return stream << std::flush;
          }
          friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Op_MsgObj const& message)
          {
              stream  // Message Header
                      >> make_LE(message.messageLength)
                      >> make_LE(message.requestId)
                      >> make_LE(message.responseTo)
                      >> make_LE(message.opCode)
                      // Message Body
                      >> make_LE(message.flags)
                      >> make_LE(message.kind)
                      >> ThorsAnvil::Serialize::bsonImporter(message.section, message.config);
              if (message.flags & OP_MsgFlag::checksumPresent) {
                  stream >> message.checksum;
              }
              return stream;
          }
  };
  template<typename Section>
  Op_MsgObj<Section> Op_Msg(Section&& section)            {return Op_MsgObj<Section>(std::forward<Section>(section));}

So with this code we can send data to Mongo and receive the reply using:
  mongoStream << Op_Msg(messageToSend);
  mongoStream >> Op_Msg(replyToMessageObject);

Conveniently for debugging we can also send the same message to std::cout or a file to make sure we are sending what we expect to send.
  std::ofstream  dump("Dump", std::ios::binary);
  dump << Op_Msg(messageToSend);

Part 2:
The Connection.
This is a wrapper around the SocketStream. The main difference is that once created it performs a handshake with the Mongo server to authenticate the user. Apart from that it should act like a normal stream.
In Mongo.h
  #ifndef THORSANVIL_DB_MONGO_MONGO_H
  #define THORSANVIL_DB_MONGO_MONGO_H

  #include "ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h"

  class Connection
  {
      using SocketStream          = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStreamBuffer>;
      private:
          SocketStream        stream;
      public:
          Connection(std::string_view host, int port,
                     std::string_view username,
                     std::string_view password,
                     std::string_view database,
                     ThorsAnvil::DB::Access::Options const& options);

          std::iostream&      getStream()     {return stream;}
  };

In Mongo.cpp
 Connection::Connection(
                              std::string_view host, int port,
                              std::string_view username,
                              std::string_view password,
                              std::string_view database,
                              ThorsAnvil::DB::Access::Options const& options)
      : stream({host, port})
  {
      std::string userNameStr{std::begin(username), std::size(username)};
      std::string passwordStr{std::begin(password), std::size(password)};
      std::string databaseStr{std::begin(database), std::size(database)};
      using std::string_literals::operator""s;

      // Get AppName
      auto findAppName = options.find("AppName");
      std::string const& appName = findAppName == options.end() ? "ThorsAnvil::Mongo Lib v1.0" : findAppName->second;
      // Get Compression
      auto findCompression = options.find("compressors");
      std::string const& compresType = findCompression == options.end() ? "" : findCompression->second;


      // Send handshake
      stream << Op_Msg(HandShake{userNameStr, databaseStr, appName, compresType});

      HandShakeReply  reply;
      stream >> Op_Msg(reply);

      if (reply.ok != 1)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::MongoConnection",
                                   "MongoConnection",
                                   "Handshake Request Failed: ",
                                   "Code: ", reply.codeName,
                                   "Msg:  ", reply.errmsg);
      }

      // Start Authorization
      ThorsAnvil::Crypto::ScramClientSha256   client(userNameStr);
      stream << Op_Msg(AuthInit{databaseStr,  "SCRAM-SHA-256"s, client.getFirstMessage()});

      AuthReply       authInitReply;
      stream >> Op_Msg(authInitReply);

      if (authInitReply.ok != 1)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::MongoConnection",
                                   "MongoConnection",
                                   "Handshake FirstMessage: ",
                                   "Code: ", authInitReply.code,
                                   "Name: ", authInitReply.codeName,
                                   "Msg:  ", authInitReply.errmsg);
      }

      stream << Op_Msg(AuthCont{authInitReply.conversationId, databaseStr, client.getProofMessage(passwordStr, authInitReply.payload.data)});

      AuthReply           authContReply;
      stream >> Op_Msg(authContReply);

      if (authContReply.ok != 1)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::MongoConnection",
                                   "MongoConnection",
                                   "Handshake Proof: ",
                                   "Code: ", authContReply.code,
                                   "Name: ", authContReply.codeName,
                                   "Msg:  ", authContReply.errmsg);
      }

      // Send Auth Cont 2: Send the DB Info
      stream << Op_Msg(AuthCont{authContReply.conversationId, databaseStr, ""s});

      AuthReply         authContReply2;
      stream >> Op_Msg(authContReply2);

      if (authContReply2.ok != 1)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::MongoConnection",
                                  "MongoConnection",
                                   "Handshake DB Connect: ",
                                   "Code: ", authContReply2.code,
                                   "Name: ", authContReply2.codeName,
                                   "Msg:  ", authContReply2.errmsg);
      }
      if (!authContReply2.done)
      {
          ThorsLogAndThrowCritical("ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo::MongoConnection",
                                  "MongoConnection",
                                   "Handshake DB Connect: ", "Expected handshake to be complete");
      }
  }

Part 3
The connection to the DB.
This represents a connection to a specific DB on the Mongo server. It has its own connection stream (std::iostream that uses TCP/IP socket). Nothing special here. On initial connection it does all the appropriate handshaking and authentication.
Note: It does not currently support compression. But I plan on adding that.
MongoDB.h
  class DB
  {
      Connection      connection;
      std::string     db;
      public:
          DB(std::string_view host, int port,
             std::string_view username,
             std::string_view password,
             std::string_view database,
             ThorsAnvil::DB::Access::Options const& options)
             : connection(host, port, username, password, database, options)
             , db(database)
          {}

          std::string const&  getName()       const   {return db;}
          std::iostream&      getStream()             {return connection.getStream();}
  };

Part 4
The insert/del command have a trivial interface. Unfortunately the find command has a sea of optional parameters. So the interface for find() exploded a bit.
The WriteConfig and ReadConfig objects contain a set of potential parameters that can be sent to Mongo. If you don't explicitly set them in the config object they are not sent to Mongo.
I could have put the "sort" and "projection" members into the readConfig object that would have stopped the find() interface from exploding into so many options. Maybe that would have been better (Not sure).
Note: The insert() and del() {delete is a reserved word} both take callback functions to report the response to the actions. This is because In the long term I want all these actions to be able to happen in parallel and long running commands to the DB could happen on a separate thread and the callback is then used to report to the main app that the operation has completed. BUT I have not done that part yet (but my stream object supports that via co-routines so that should be a simple add).
  class Collection
  {
      DB&             db;
      std::string     collection;
      WriteConfig     writeConfig;
      ReadConfig      readConfig;
      public:
          Collection(DB& db, std::string const& collection, WriteConfig&& defaultWriteConfig = WriteConfig{}, ReadConfig&& defaultReadConfig = ReadConfig{})
              : db(db)
              , collection(collection)
              , writeConfig(std::move(defaultWriteConfig))
              , readConfig(std::move(defaultReadConfig))
          {}

          std::string const& getName()        const {return collection;}
          std::string const& getDBName()      const {return db.getName();}
          WriteConfig const& getWriteConfig() const {return writeConfig;}
          ReadConfig  const& getReadConfig()  const {return readConfig;}

          void setWriteConfig(WriteConfig&& c)      {writeConfig = std::move(c);}
          void setReadConfig(ReadConfig&& c)        {readConfig = std::move(c);}

          template<typename T>
          void insert(T const& doc, std::function<void(WriteResponse const&)>&& action = [](WriteResponse const&){})                      {insert(doc, getWriteConfig(), std::move(action));}
          template<typename T>
          void insert(T const& doc, WriteConfig const& config, std::function<void(WriteResponse const&)>&& action = [](WriteResponse const&){});
          // Suggestions for T
          //      std::tuple<Doc1&, Doc2&>
          //      std::vector<Doc>
          //      std::array<N, Doc>


          template<typename... Q>
          void del(std::tuple<Query<Q>&...> const& doc, std::function<void(WriteResponse const&)>&& action = [](WriteResponse const&){}) {del(doc, getWriteConfig(), std::move(action));}
          template<typename... Q>
          void del(std::tuple<Query<Q>&...> const& doc, WriteConfig const& config, std::function<void(WriteResponse const&)>&& action = [](WriteResponse const&){});

          template<typename T>
          void find()                                                                         {findAction<T, NoOp, NoOp, NoOp>(Query{NoOp{}}, NoOp{}, NoOp{}, getReadConfig());}
          template<typename T>
          void find(ReadConfig const& rConfig)                                                {findAction<T, NoOp, NoOp, NoOp>(Query{NoOp{}}, NoOp{}, NoOp{}, rConfig);}
          template<typename T, typename Q>
          void find(Query<Q> const& filter)                                                   {findAction<T, Q, NoOp, NoOp>(filter, NoOp{}, NoOp{}, getReadConfig());}
          template<typename T, typename Q>
          void find(Query<Q> const& filter, ReadConfig const& rConfig)                        {findAction<T, Q, NoOp, NoOp>(filter, NoOp{}, NoOp{}, rConfig);}
          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Proj>
          void find(Query<Q> const& filter, Proj const& projection)                           {findAction<T, Q, Proj, NoOp>(filter, projection, NoOp{}, getReadConfig());}
          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Proj>
          void find(Query<Q> const& filter, Proj const& projection, ReadConfig const& rConfig){findAction<T, Q, Proj, NoOp>(filter, projection, NoOp{}, rConfig);}

          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Sort>
          void findSort(Query<Q> const& filter, Sort const& sort)                             {findAction<T, Q, NoOp, Sort>(filter, NoOp{}, sort, getReadConfig());}
          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Sort>
          void findSort(Query<Q> const& filter, Sort const& sort, ReadConfig const& rConfig)  {findAction<T, Q, NoOp, Sort>(filter, NoOp{}, sort, rConfig);}
          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Proj, typename Sort>
          void findSort(Query<Q> const& filter, Proj const& projection, Sort const& sort)     {findAction<T, Q, Proj, Sort>(filter, projection, sort, getReadConfig());}
          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Proj, typename Sort>
          void findSort(Query<Q> const& filter, Proj const& projection, Sort const& sort, ReadConfig const& rConfig)
                                                                                              {findAction<T, Q, Proj, Sort>(filter, projection, sort, rConfig);}
      private:
          template<typename T, typename Q, typename Proj, typename Sort>
          void findAction(Query<Q> const& filter, Proj const& projection, Sort const& sort, ReadConfig const& readConfig);
  };

But the implementation seems relatively trivial:
Part 4a: Insert
  template<typename T>
  void Collection::insert(T const& doc, WriteConfig const& config, std::function<void(WriteResponse const&)>&& action)
  {
      db.getStream() << Op_Msg(Inserter<T>{*this, doc, config});

      WriteResponse    response;
      db.getStream() >> Op_Msg(response);
      action(response);
  }

Part 4B: Delete
  template<typename... Q>
  void Collection::del(std::tuple<Query<Q>&...> const& doc, WriteConfig const& config, std::function<void(WriteResponse const&)>&& action)
  {
      db.getStream() << Op_Msg(Deleter<std::tuple<Query<Q> const&...>>{*this, doc, config});

      WriteResponse    response;
      db.getStream() >> Op_Msg(response);
      action(response);
  }

Part 4C: Find
  template<typename T, typename Q, typename Proj, typename Sort>
  void Collection::findAction(Query<Q> const& filter, Proj const& projection, Sort const& sort, ReadConfig const& config)
  {
      std::vector<T>  result;

      db.getStream() << Op_Msg(Finder<Q, Proj, Sort>{*this, filter, projection, sort, config});

      FindResponse<T> response{result};
      db.getStream() >> Op_MsgDebug(response);

      std::int64_t    cursor = response.cursor.id;
      while (cursor != 0)
      {
          db.getStream() << Op_Msg(GetMore{*this, response, config});

          GetMoreResponse<T>    nextResponse{result};
          db.getStream() >> Op_Msg(nextResponse);

          cursor = nextResponse.cursor.id;
      }
      //action(result);
  }

Part 5 Config objects
These object contain a set of optinal parameters that can be sent to Mongo.
The config object holds each value plus a member "filter".
The "Filter" member is used by the serialization library to determine if the object should be placed on the output stream. So by marking it false it will not be serialized.
I have an idea for using std::optional in the serialization library but have not implemented that yet.
The Config and ConfigBuilder is something I stole from a Java pattern. Its a bit of an experiment so that I can construct in imutable Config object without having to have a billion different constructors.
Usage:
Config f = ConfgiBuild{}.option1(1).options2(2).option3(68).build(); 

Part 5a: Write Config
  class WriteConfigBuilder;
  class WriteConfig
  {
      bool                ordered                     = true; // Optional     Def: Stop on first failure
      std::int32_t        maxTimeMS                   = 0;    // Optional     Def: No timeout
      WriteConcerns       writeConcern;                       // Optional     Note: Don't set in transactions
      bool                bypassDocumentValidation    = false;// Optional     Def: Validation done
      std::string         comment;                            // Optional     comment add to logs
      Filter              filter;
      public:
          friend class WriteConfigBuilder;
          WriteConfig()
          {
              filter["ordered"] = false;
              filter["maxTimeMS"] = false;
              filter["writeConcern"] = false;
              filter["bypassDocumentValidation"] = false;
              filter["collation"] = false;
              filter["comment"] = false;
          }

          bool            const&  getOrdered()                    const {return ordered;}
          std::int32_t    const&  getMaxTimeMS()                  const {return maxTimeMS;}
          WriteConcerns   const&  getWriteConcern()               const {return writeConcern;}
          bool            const&  getBypassDocumentValidation()   const {return bypassDocumentValidation;}
          std::string     const&  getComment()                    const {return comment;}

          Filter          const&  getFilter()                     const {return filter;}
  };
  class WriteConfigBuilder
  {
      WriteConfig  result;

      public:
          WriteConfigBuilder()
          {}
          WriteConfigBuilder(WriteConfig&& config)
              : result(std::move(config))
          {}
          WriteConfig build()                                      {return result;}

          WriteConfigBuilder& ordered(bool v)                      {result.ordered = v;                    result.filter["ordered"] = true;                    return *this;}
          WriteConfigBuilder& maxTimeMS(std::int32_t v)            {result.maxTimeMS = v;                  result.filter["maxTimeMS"] = true;                  return *this;}
          WriteConfigBuilder& writeConcern(WriteConcerns const& v) {result.writeConcern = v;               result.filter["writeConcern"] = true;               return *this;}
          WriteConfigBuilder& bypassDocumentValidation(bool v)     {result.bypassDocumentValidation = v;   result.filter["bypassDocumentValidation"] = true;   return *this;}
          WriteConfigBuilder& comment(std::string v)               {result.comment = v;                    result.filter["comment"] = true;                    return *this;}
  };

Part 5B: Read Config
  class ReadConfigBuilder;
  class ReadConfig
  {
      std::string         hint;
      std::int32_t        skip;
      std::int32_t        limit;
      std::int32_t        batchSize;
      bool                singleBatch;
      std::string         comment;
      std::int32_t        maxTimeMS;
      bool                returnKey;
      bool                showRecordId;
      bool                tailable;
      bool                oplogReplay;
      bool                noCursorTimeout;
      bool                awaitData;
      bool                allowPartialResults;
      bool                allowDiskUse;

      Filter              filter;

      public:
          friend class ReadConfigBuilder;
          ReadConfig()
          {
              filter["hint"] = false;
              filter["skip"] = false;
              filter["limit"] = false;
              filter["batchSize"] = false;
              filter["singleBatch"] = false;
              filter["comment"] = false;
              filter["maxTimeMS"] = false;
              filter["readConcern"] = false;
              filter["max"]    = false;
              filter["min"]    = false;
              filter["returnKey"] = false;
              filter["showRecordId"] = false;
              filter["tailable"] = false;
              filter["oplogReplay"] = false;
              filter["noCursorTimeout"] = false;
              filter["awaitData"] = false;
              filter["allowPartialResults"] = false;
              filter["collation"] = false;
              filter["allowDiskUse"] = false;
              filter["let"] = false;
          }

          std::string     const& getHint()               const{return hint;}
          std::int32_t    const& getSkip()               const{return skip;}
          std::int32_t    const& getLimit()              const{return limit;}
          std::int32_t    const& getBatchSize()          const{return batchSize;}
          bool            const& getSingleBatch()        const{return singleBatch;}
          std::string     const& getComment()            const{return comment;}
          std::int32_t    const& getMaxTimeMS()          const{return maxTimeMS;}
          bool            const& getReturnKey()          const{return returnKey;}
          bool            const& getShowRecordId()       const{return tailable;}
          bool            const& getTailable()           const{return oplogReplay;}
          bool            const& getOplogReplay()        const{return noCursorTimeout;}
          bool            const& getNoCursorTimeout()    const{return awaitData;}
          bool            const& getAwaitData()          const{return allowPartialResults;}
          bool            const& getAllowPartialResults()const{return allowPartialResults;}
          bool            const& getAllowDiskUse()       const{return allowDiskUse;}


          Filter          const&  getFilter()            const {return filter;}
  };
class ReadConfigBuilder
  {
      ReadConfig  result;

      public:
          ReadConfigBuilder()
          {}
          ReadConfigBuilder(ReadConfig&& config)
              : result(std::move(config))
          {}
          ReadConfig build()                                  {return result;}

          ReadConfigBuilder& skip(std::int32_t v)             {result.skip = v;               result.filter["skip"] = true;               return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& limit(std::int32_t v)            {result.limit = v;              result.filter["limit"] = true;              return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& batchSize(std::int32_t v)        {result.batchSize = v;          result.filter["batchSize"] = true;          return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& singleBatch(bool v)              {result.singleBatch = v;        result.filter["singleBatch"] = true;        return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& comment(std::string v)           {result.comment = v;            result.filter["comment"] = true;            return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& maxTimeMS(std::int32_t v)        {result.maxTimeMS = v;          result.filter["maxTimeMS"] = true;          return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& returnKey(bool v)                {result.returnKey = v;          result.filter["returnKey"] = true;          return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& showRecordId(bool v)             {result.showRecordId = v;       result.filter["showRecordId"] = true;       return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& tailable(bool v)                 {result.tailable = v;           result.filter["tailable"] = true;           return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& oplogReplay(bool v)              {result.oplogReplay = v;        result.filter["oplogReplay"] = true;        return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& noCursorTimeout(bool v)          {result.noCursorTimeout = v;    result.filter["noCursorTimeout"] = true;    return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& awaitData(bool v)                {result.awaitData = v;          result.filter["awaitData"] = true;          return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& allowPartialResults(bool v)      {result.allowPartialResults = v;result.filter["allowPartialResults"] = true;return *this;}
          ReadConfigBuilder& allowDiskUse(bool v)             {result.allowDiskUse = v;       result.filter["allowDiskUse"] = true;       return *this;}
  };


Remove support for big-endian systems
Unless you want your code to run natively on an IBM z/Architecture mainframe, there are basically no computers used anymore that run (let alone support) big-endian mode. I would recommend that you remove your code that supports big-endian machines, as it will not be used, thus rarely tested, and will only be a potential source of bugs and inefficiency.
Note that you are already assuming that bytes are 8 bits and that your code runs on machines that support 32-bit integers.
Don't make members mutable if not necessary
I don't see why the protected member variables of Op_MsgObj need to be mutable. You would only use that for some very specific use cases, like needing a mutex to guard access, or if you do some caching of expensive calculations.
In your case, remove mutable, then remove const from the operator>>() overload defined in Op_MsgObj.
class Connection can be replaced by a function
The class Connection just constructs a stream. That's it. It could be replaced by a single function:
SocketStream connectToDB(std::string_view host, int port,
                         std::string_view username,
                         std::string_view password,
                         std::string_view database,
                         ThorsAnvil::DB::Access::Options const& options) {
    SocketStream stream({host, port});
    …
    return stream;
}

Another option would be to make Connection actually be a stream itself, perhaps by just publicly inheriting from SocketStream. Or just fold the code into class DB.
Weird use of callback functions
Collection::insert() and Collection::del() both take an action parameter, which is a callback function that gets called with the response object. I don't know why it is designed like this. Either I would just return response from those functions so the caller can do what it wants with them without having to provide a callback function, or just remove it altogether if the caller is never going to do that.
There is a default callback declared for each overload, one of the overloads calls the other overload and moves the action along with it, wouldn't that create an infinite loop? It looks dodgy in any case. Why not just write:
WriteResponse insert(T const& doc) {
    return insert(doc, getWriteConfig());
}

WriteResponse insert(T const& doc, WriteConfig const& config) {
    db.getStream() << Op_Msg(Inserter<T>{*this, doc, config});
    WriteResponse response;
    db.getStream() >> Op_Msg(response);
    return response;
}

About the builder pattern
Using a builder interface is nice, but you are implementing it incorrectly. The goal of the builder is to construct an object with all the right parameters in one go. That constructor can then verify the combination of all those parameters is correct, and there will never be an object in a half-configured, potentially invalid state. So either fix this:
class WriteConfig {
    bool ordered; // default values not needed in this case
    std::int32_t maxTimeMS;
    …
public:
    // no friend declaration needed
    WriteConfig(bool ordered, std::int32_t maxTimeMS, …)
        : ordered(ordered)
        , maxTimeMS(maxTimeMS)
        , …
    {}
    …
};

class WriteConfigBuilder {
    bool m_ordered = true;
    std::int32_t m_maxTimeMS = 0;
    …
public:
    // rule of zero
    WriteConfig build() const {
        return WriteConfig(m_ordered, m_maxTimeMS, …);
    }
    WriteConfigBuilder& ordered(bool v)           { m_ordered = v; }
    WriteConfigBuilder& maxTimeMS(std::int32_t v) { m_maxTimeMS = v; }
    …
};

Or if you don't need that atomic construction, just move the setters from the builder directly into the type of object you want to create:
class WriteConfig {
    bool m_ordered = true;
    std::int32_t m_maxTimeMS = 0;
    …
public:
    // rule of zero
    WriteConfig& ordered(bool v)           { m_ordered = v; }
    WriteConfig& maxTimeMS(std::int32_t v) { m_maxTimeMS = v; }
    …
};

In the latter case, it even simplifies things a bit, in your example main() for example you'd then write:
collection.find<Person>(Query<AgeGreaterThan>{18}, ReadConfig{}.batchSize(5));

Lack of error checking?
I am seeing very little error checking in your code. The only hope is that all the stream operators called in your program throw exceptions on errors. The streams from the standard library do not however.

It's really irritating that there is no standard (just using the standard libraries) to detect endianness at compile time. I would like to do what you suggest and basically put a static assert that generates an error on big endian systems.

Found it: !!! #include <bit> Then static_assert(std::endian::little == std::endian::native);

https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsMongo/issues/1
https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsMongo/issues/2
https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsMongo/issues/3
https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsMongo/issues/4
https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsMongo/issues/5
